# Issues with Laratrust usage

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to use Laratrust for my Laravel 5.6 project, and I'm confused with this syntax on their docs.

Where should I use this example, the controller, laratrust-seeder, or what?

```
$owner = new Role();
$owner->name         = 'owner';
$owner->display_name = 'Project Owner'; // optional
$owner->description  = 'User is the owner of a given project'; // optional
$owner->save();

$admin = new Role();
$admin->name         = 'admin';
$admin->display_name = 'User Administrator'; // optional
$admin->description  = 'User is allowed to manage and edit other users'; // optional
$admin->save();
```

Comment: To answer your question, it entirely depends on how your application will work. If you need a fixed set of roles, it'd make sense to create them in a seeder. If new roles can be created via your application, then you'd need the functionality in a controller too.

Comment: Okay, its the latter, but how would that look like please?

Comment: To save answering this, have a Google for a Laravel CRUD tutorial or example. There are loads.

Comment: Take a look in the issues on their github page. Someone made an entire gui to add roles, permissions, etc

Answer (score 0):

The laratrust   [Documentation Page](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/installation.html)  has been updated
The code above creates roles for users in your application

```
$owner = Role::create([
    'name' => 'owner',
    'display_name' => 'Project Owner', // optional
    'description' => 'User is the owner of a given project', // optional
]);

$admin = Role::create([
    'name' => 'admin',
    'display_name' => 'User Administrator', // optional
    'description' => 'User is allowed to manage and edit other users', // optional
]);
```